# Ввод даты в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, консоль

Пишу программу в С#, которая предполагает простое анкетирование пользователей с последующем выводом данных.

Как правильно организовать в консольном приложении C# получение от пользователя данных о дате его рождения?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Сделайте метод, который в цикле опрашивает ввод, пока не будет введено правильное значение:

```
DateTime inputDoB()
{
    DateTime dob; // date of birth
    string input;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите дату рождения в формате дд.ММ.гггг (день.месяц.год):");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dob));

    return dob;
}
```

Использование:

```
var dob = inputDoB();
```

Можно задать произвольный [формат](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) вводимой даты. Например, `"d.M.yyyy"`, что позволит вводить дату в виде `1.4.2017`.

Comment: Не принимает в качестве ввода `"1.04.2017"`.

Comment: @VladD, ну так написано "Введите дату рождения в формате дд.ММ.гггг", ваш ввод не соответствует маске... Хотя, конечно, для пользователя это может быть мучительно

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - большое спасибо!

Answer (score 12):

Всё зависит от ваших требований, если достаточно простого ручного ввода, то можно воспользоваться одним из ответов, присланных ранее.

Если вы реализуете консольный графический интерфейс, можно придумать что-то наподобие такого:

```
class ConsoleDatePicker
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

    public ConsoleDatePicker(int left, int top)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public ConsoleDatePicker() : this(0, 0) { }

    string[] months = { "янв", "фев", "мар", "апр", "май", "июн", "июл", "авг", "сен", "окт", "ноя", "дек" };

    public void Show()
    {
        int oldLeft = Console.CursorLeft, oldTop = Console.CursorTop;
        ShowFrame();
        ShowMonth();
        ShowCursor();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
    }

    void ShowFrame()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
        Console.Write("╔══════════════════════╗");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 1);
        Console.Write("║                      ║");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 2);
        Console.Write("╟──────────────────────╢");
        for (int topAdd = 3; topAdd <= 15; ++topAdd)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + topAdd);
            Console.Write("║                      ║");
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 16);
        Console.Write("╚══════════════════════╝");
    }

    void ShowMonth()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 1);
        Console.Write($"║       {months[SelectedDate.Month - 1]} {SelectedDate.Year:0000}       ║");
        string[,] days = new string[6, 7];
        int week = 0;
        int dayOfWeek = (int)FirstDayOfMonth(SelectedDate).DayOfWeek - 1;
        if (dayOfWeek == -1) dayOfWeek = 6;
        int daysInMonth = LastDayOfMonth(SelectedDate).Day;
        for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; ++day)
        {
            days[week, dayOfWeek] = $"{day,2}";
            ++dayOfWeek;
            if (dayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                ++week;
                dayOfWeek = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; ++row)
            for (int column = 0; column < 7; ++column)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 2 + column * 3, Top + 4 + row * 2);
                Console.Write(days[row, column] ?? "  ");
            }
    }

    void ShowCursor()
    {
        int column = (int)SelectedDate.DayOfWeek - 1;
        if (column == -1) column = 6;
        int row = (SelectedDate.Day + (int)FirstDayOfMonth(SelectedDate).DayOfWeek - 2) / 7;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 3 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("┌──┐");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 4 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("│");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 4 + column * 3, Top + 4 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("│");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 5 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("└──┘");
    }

    void EraseCursor()
    {
        int column = (int)SelectedDate.DayOfWeek - 1;
        if (column == -1) column = 6;
        int row = (SelectedDate.Day + (int)FirstDayOfMonth(SelectedDate).DayOfWeek - 2) / 7;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 3 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("    ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 4 + row * 2);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 4 + column * 3, Top + 4 + row * 2);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + 1 + column * 3, Top + 5 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("    ");
    }

    DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(DateTime date)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    }

    DateTime LastDayOfMonth(DateTime date)
    {
        return FirstDayOfMonth(date.AddMonths(1)).AddDays(-1);
    }

    public DateTime GetDate()
    {
        int oldLeft = Console.CursorLeft, oldTop = Console.CursorTop;
        bool cursorVisible = Console.CursorVisible;
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            DateTime newDate = SelectedDate;
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow) newDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(1);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow) newDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(-1);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow) newDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(7);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow) newDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(-7);
            if (newDate != SelectedDate)
            {
                EraseCursor();
                bool changeMonth = newDate.Month != SelectedDate.Month;
                SelectedDate = newDate;
                if (changeMonth) ShowMonth();
                ShowCursor();
            }
        }
        while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.CursorVisible = cursorVisible;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
        return SelectedDate;
    }
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
        ConsoleDatePicker cdp = new ConsoleDatePicker(5, 5);
        cdp.Show();
        DateTime date = cdp.GetDate();
        Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали {0:d}", date);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Еще один вариант для использования в консольном GUI, более простой, менее громоздкий и, скорее всего, более удобный. Без использования псевдографики, поэтому не зависит от используемой кодовой страницы (хотя в разных культурах представление даты должно быть разным dd.MM.yyyy/yyyy-MM-dd - при желании реализуете самостоятельно).

```
class ConsoleDatePickerMini
{
    public int Left { get; }
    public int Top { get; }
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; private set; }

    public ConsoleDatePickerMini(int left, int top, DateTime date)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        SelectedDate = date;
    }

    public ConsoleDatePickerMini(int left, int top) : this(left, top, DateTime.Today) { }

    public ConsoleDatePickerMini() : this(0, 0) { }

    public void Show()
    {
        int oldLeft = Console.CursorLeft, oldTop = Console.CursorTop;
        ShowDate();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
    }

    public DateTime GetDate()
    {
        int oldLeft = Console.CursorLeft, oldTop = Console.CursorTop;
        bool cursorVisible = Console.CursorVisible;
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        int f = 0;
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        do
        {
            ShowCursor(f);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow) f = (f + 1) % 3;
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow) f = (f + 2) % 3;
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow ||
                key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                int additive = key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow ? 1 : -1;
                if (f == 0) SelectedDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(additive);
                else if (f == 1) SelectedDate = SelectedDate.AddMonths(additive);
                else if (f == 2) SelectedDate = SelectedDate.AddYears(additive);
            }
            ShowDate();
        }
        while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.CursorVisible = cursorVisible;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldLeft, oldTop);
        return SelectedDate;
    }

    void ShowDate()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
        Console.Write("          ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 1);
        Console.Write(SelectedDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top + 2);
        Console.Write("          ");
    }

    void ShowCursor(int field)
    {
        int offset = new[] { 1, 4, 9 }[field]; // или по хакерски: int offset = (field + 1) * (field + 1);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + offset, Top);
        Console.Write("+");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left + offset, Top + 2);
        Console.Write("-");
    }
}
```

Использование аналогично предыдущему. Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! Правда, в японской локали (-_-, приходится иногда в ней работать) "вёрстка" нарушена. Логику вывода в этой локали понять может только просветлённый сенсей.

Comment: @Андрей - очень круто! Но для моего понимания пока еще слишком сложно. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите дату рождения в формате (DD.MM.YYYY): \n");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] split = input.Split('.');
double day = Double.Parse(split[0]);
double month = Double.Parse(split[1]);
double year = Double.Parse(split[2]);
```

Comment: `1,5.7,8.2016,3` при русской локали - дальше что?

Comment: это проблемы юзера-дауна. Код здесь ни при чем.

Comment: А я бы сказал, что программиста, который с какого-то перепуга хранит день месяц и год как `double`.

Comment: @Exodium: У хорошего программиста программа не должна падать при любом вводе пользователя. У вас упадёт, например, при вводе `привет`. Чините!

Comment: @Exodium - Большое спасибо!