# Как вывести календарь в cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, администрирование

Требуется вывести календарь на определенный месяц в командной строке Windows,
в Linux была утилита calc, если ли в Windows что то похожее?

Comment: Вроде как это невозможно с настройками по умолчанию... Максимально близкая команда к требуемой будет `date`, выведет `The current date is: 25.05.2017
Enter the new date: (dd-mm-yy)`

Comment: Сделать собственную утилитку, использовав код наподобие [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655959/184217).

Comment: Максимально близкая команда - date /T, зачем нам устаналвивать новую дату?)

Comment: В cmd точно никак, как посмотреть текущую дату уже написали. Возможно что-то есть в PowerShell, но что-то я сильно сомневаюсь. До линуксовых возможностей  что cmd, что ps еще не доросли, и вряд ли уже дорастут. Так что присоединяюсь к  AlexanderPetrov, пишите свою утилиту.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас Питон установлен:

```
c:\> python -mcalendar 2018 3
     March 2018
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: а текущую дату он может показать?

Comment: по умолчанию календарь за текущий год печатается.

Answer (score 0):

В тело .bat файла можно вставить вызов VB-скрипта:

```
cscript cal.vbs //nologo
```

Код скрипта:

```
dt = Date
m=Month(dt)
y=year(dt)
ld = cbyte( Day(DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt)+1, 0)) )
fd = weekday(DateSerial(y, m, 1),2)
wscript.stdout.writeline "   "&MonthName(m) &" "& y

For i =1 to 7 step 1 
 s = s + weekdayname(i,true,2) + " "
next
wscript.stdout.writeline s

For j = 0 to 4 step 1
 s =""
 For i = 1 to 7 step 1
  d=j*7 + i
       if d<10 then ss=" "&CStr(d) else ss=CStr(d) end if
     if (d<fd or  d>ld ) then ss="  "   end if
  s=s+ss+" "
 Next
 wscript.stdout.writeline s
Next
```

Если возникнет необходимость использовать VB-скрипт внутри .bat файла, то лучше воспользоваться стандартными функциями перенаправления выводимого текста в файл:

```
echo dt = Date>>cal.vbs
...
```