# Создание кнопки в консоли на C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Возможно ли добавить в консольное приложение кнопку? Чтобы пользователь не вводил сообщение сам, а нажимал на слово и получал результат. Своеобразный гипертекст для консоли.

Comment: а в чем смысл?не лучше ли использовать хотя бы винформы?

Comment: C# - мой первый ЯП. Смотрю бесплатный курс, в процессе которого создаю тематическое приложение. Кнопки бы очень облегчили мне тестирование кода. Формами я пока не пользовался, а изучал синтаксис.

Comment: Но если прям очень нужно, то https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971246/3129992

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655959/184217 - меня впечатлил этот пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то такое:

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose your destiny:");

int top = Console.CursorTop;
int y = top;

Console.WriteLine("One");
Console.WriteLine("Two");
Console.WriteLine("Three");

int down = Console.CursorTop;

Console.CursorSize = 100;
Console.CursorTop = top;

ConsoleKey key;
while ((key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        if (y > top)
        {
            y--;
            Console.CursorTop = y;
        }
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
    {
        if (y < down - 1)
        {
            y++;
            Console.CursorTop = y;
        }
    }
}

Console.CursorTop = down;

if (y == top)
    Console.WriteLine("один");
else if (y == top + 1)
    Console.WriteLine("два");
else if (y == top + 2)
    Console.WriteLine("три");
```

Пользователю выводится список, по которому он может перемещаться, нажимая клавиши вверх и вниз. После чего сделать выбор, нажав Enter.

---

При желании, можно добавить в консольное приложение графическое окошко. Но лучше так не делать, а сразу создавать оконное приложение.

Добавьте в проект ссылку на сборку System.Windows.Forms.dll.

После чего можно сваять следующее:

```
var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

var form = new Form();

var listBox = new ListBox { Parent = form };
listBox.DataSource = list;

var button = new Button { Parent = form, Text = "OK", Left = 200, Top = 230, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
form.AcceptButton = button;

form.ShowDialog();

var value = (string)listBox.SelectedValue;
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Тут всё просто: создали форму, на неё поместили листбокс, к нему привязали список с нужными значениями. Также на форму помещаем кнопку и настраиваем необходимые свойства так, чтобы нажатие клавиши Ввод (Enter) закрывало форму.

После закрытия окна получаем из листбокса выбранный пункт.