# Консольное меню на c#

Tags: c#, консоль, menu

Я нашел кучу примеров, но все они либо настолько плохие, что я не знаю как даже их них что-то сделать хорошее, либо они не решают моей проблемы. (а на англоязычном стаке наоборот сложные примеры)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool bTest = true;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Пункт 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Пункт 2");

            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo ck = Console.ReadKey();
                switch (ck.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Пункт 1");
                        Console.WriteLine("Пункт 2");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Пункт 1");
                        Console.WriteLine("Пункт 2");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                        if (bTest)
                        {
                            //Метод 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Метод 2;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог:

1. Перемещаться по меню стрелочками (вроде как реализовано, только иногда приходится два раза нажимать на стрелочку).
2. Чтобы выбранный пункт подсвечивался цветом.
3. Нажатием enter этот пункт выполнялся (это вроде как реализовал, но почему-то он выполняет всегда только первый пункт и не очищает перед этим консоль).
4. Была возможность вернуться в главное меню после выполненного одного из пунктов

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984789/184217 - гляньте это

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280462/373567 - ООП вас спасет

Comment: @aepot Мне до ООП еще далеко, очень

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin почитайте пример по ссылке, там ничего космически сложного, даже делегатов нет, хотя они очень напрашиваются к вашей задаче. Что такое классы - вы же знаете.

Comment: @aepot Знаю, но еще не должен использовать

Comment: А как же класс `Program`? :) он обладает теми же свойствами, что и любой другой класс. Если вам запрещено использовать ООП (в чем я сильно сомневаюсь), берите все методы и поля из примера, перетаскивайте к себе в Program, делайте их `static` и будет почти готово.

Comment: @aepot Вот переход стрелкам это явно то, что нужно, а скорее всего основной метод нужно все же реализовать по другому, как вариант я думаю о двух методах в которых будут циклы для перемещения, но такой реализации найти не могу

Comment: @aepot Ну я имел в виду за исключением Program, ООП я в целом не изучал, поэтому плохо понимаю, что вы имеете в виду, а если так, то и в дальнейшем сам не объяснить что у меня написано, можно реализовать примерно то же через for'ы?

Comment: Сейчас напишу пример.

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/how+to+make+a+navigation+bar+in+a+console+app+c%23
Вот это для меня еще более менее понятно

Comment: Я примерно о таком цикле говорю, только там много условий уже не так хорошо понятных, но разобраться можно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот самый черновой пример. Если вы с ООП не знакомы, то хотя-бы методы то создавать, надеюсь умеете.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] menuItems = new string[] { "Пункт 1", "Пункт 2", "Выход" };

    Console.WriteLine("Меню");
    Console.WriteLine();

    int row = Console.CursorTop;
    int col = Console.CursorLeft;
    int index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        DrawMenu(menuItems, row, col, index);
        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                if (index < menuItems.Length - 1)
                    index++;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                if (index > 0)
                    index--;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                switch (index)
                {
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Выбран выход из приложения");
                        return;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine($"Выбран пункт {menuItems[index]}");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void DrawMenu(string[] items, int row, int col, int index)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас оно работает, я правильно понял?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin не понял вопроса, у вас не работает?

Comment: Да, вывод происходит, но он окончательный, взаимодействие не удается
(возможна проблема несовместимости (у меня macOS, но такого не было когда я пробовал другие меню)

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin не понимаю, возможно проблема с цветами, попробуйте явно задавать цвета для выделенного пункта. Замените `Console.ResetColor();` тоже на явное задание цвета фона и тона. В любом случае по нажатию Enter должно что-то писать.

Comment: Да, и правда, работает

Comment: Спасибо большое, основа и главное понятная теперь есть, буду пытаться делать что-то дальше с ним

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin не за что, рад что помог.

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin подсказка, пригодится в будущем `new string('x', N)` создает строку, состоящую только из символов `x` длиной `N`. Это позволит например избежать затирания строчки пробелами в цикле.