# Помогите доделать меню

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Cars{
     public string name;
     public int rang;
     public string frac;
    
     public Cars(string n,int m,string g){
         this.name = n;
         this.rang = m;
         this.frac = g;
     }
}

class HelloWorld {
   static void Main() {
      List s = new List();
      s.Add( new Cars("Infinity FX 50s",9,"ems") );
      s.Add( new Cars("Alfa romeo gulia ",9,"fib") );
      s.Add( new Cars("Infinity qx 60",10,"sd") );
     
     
      Console.WriteLine("Меню");
      Console.WriteLine("1)Удалить:");
      Console.WriteLine("2)Перезаписать:");
      Console.WriteLine("3)Добавить:");
      Console.WriteLine("Выберите пункт:");
  q1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     
   }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338675/373567

Comment: Самостоятельно отладка производилась? Есть [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Это здоровенная портянка кода, в которой едва ли кто возьмется разбираться - уважайте время участников сообщества.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Cars
{
    public string name;
    public int rang;
    public string frac;

    public Cars(string n, int m, string g)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.rang = m;
        this.frac = g;
    }
}

class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List <Cars> s = new List<Cars>();
        s.Add(new Cars("Infinity FX 50s", 9, "ems"));
        s.Add(new Cars("Alfa romeo gulia ", 9, "fib"));
        s.Add(new Cars("Infinity qx 60", 10, "sd"));


        Console.WriteLine("Меню");
        Console.WriteLine("1)Удалить:");
        Console.WriteLine("2)Перезаписать:");
        Console.WriteLine("3)Добавить:");
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите пункт:");
        int q1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }
}
```