# Календарь и DateTime

Tags: c#

В метод у меня прилетает дата, я смотрю сколько дней в месяце, все работает и печатает, только вот первое число у меня всегда понедельник.

Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб Вс <---- должно под нужной колонкой рисовать цифру в соответствии с месяцем.

```
public static void DrowCalendar(DateTime date)
{
    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    int posX = 44, posY = 18;
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
         Console.SetCursorPosition(posX, posY);
         Console.Write(i);
         if (i % 7 == 0)
              {
                   posY++;
                   posX = 40;
                   Console.WriteLine();
              }
              posX += 4;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Проблема то в чем?

Comment: У меня первое число всегда Понедельник, что не есть правильно

Comment: но код, которым вы понедельники выводите, вы не покажете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655959/218063