# Структура проекта. Консольное приложение С++

Tags: c++

Как должна выглядеть структура проекта? Есть ли какие-то паттерны в c++? Какие файлы в какие папки создавать?

Comment: Формально, FAR - консольный. Borland C++ 3.1 - тоже. С мышью что-то делать можно, но я понятия не имею, как.

Comment: Вопрос: "Кто работал?" Ответ: "Я". Ответ получен? Закрываем тему? Или всё же нормально озаглавите свой вопрос?

Comment: Начинать проект нужно с создания репозитория на Гитхабе.

Comment: Куда вы собрались добавлять кнопку в консоль? | PS: можно сделать как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655959/184217)

Comment: Слушайте ваше консольное приложение по сути тот же процесс, что и все остальные только без графической оболочки. Примеров масса службы, утилиты ...

Comment: Куда вы собрались добавлять кнопку??? Откройте консоль (cmd.exe) и помедитируйте - сколько кнопок вы видите?

Comment: Консоль и граф оболочка это для юзера. Т.е все остальное у них одинаковое классы стили точка входа (main) все так ка есть. Как пример создайте веб службу которая будет обрабатывать сложные запросы

Comment: Работа с базой любой бек енд которому не нужно большое вмешательство. Старт стоп ...

Comment: Win32 не подразумевает графическую оболочку. Она подразумевает платформу

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov странно, с созданием репозитория на гитхабе я наоборот завершаю свои проекты

Comment: @MisterADC, FAR может, значит и ты можешь.

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: Можно и футбол затеить только вот зачем?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleMode(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleHandle,
  _In_ DWORD  dwMode
);
```

> `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` (0x0010)
>
> If the mouse pointer is within the borders of the console window and the window has the keyboard focus, mouse events generated by mouse movement and button presses are placed in the input buffer. These events are discarded by ReadFile or ReadConsole, even when this mode is enabled.

Подробнее [где-то тут](https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/master/enc/enc_eng/meta/winapi/mouse_event_record.html) и даже [версия на русском](https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/master/enc/enc_rus/meta/winapi/mouse_event_record.html).