# Как реализовать метод c#

Tags: c#

Не могу понять как реализовать метод.
Есть некоторый фал, в котором содержатся данные о пользователе. У пользователя есть id дата создания и т.д. Так вот, метод должен выводить в консоль всех пользователей из диапазона дат создания. Подскажите как подойти к решению? В c# я новичок. Пытаюсь разобраться сам.

Comment: Зависит от формата файла, и от целей. Например если в файле идет построчно что-то вроде `Вася;15`, то можем сделать такое: `var result = File.ReadAllLines("File.txt").Split(';').Select(x=>new User{ Name = x[0], Age = x[1] }).Where(x=>x is { Age: >18 and <30 });`, вот вам даже методы не нужны, небольшая LINQ строка, ну а если вам надо "для учебы", то вспоминаем ООП, вспоминаем SOLID, понимаем, что это все надо разделить на составляющие, а не один конкретный метод, где за конкретную задачу (например разбор файла) отвечает конкретный метод.

Comment: Дата создания пользователя = ДР - 9 мес.?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое! Благодаря вам, появилось какое-никакое понимание того, что нужну сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самыми элементарными действиями:

1. Ввести начало диапазона дат создания.
2. Ввести конец диапазона дат создания.
3. Читать файл построчно:

   а) разобрать строку - извлечь id и дату создания;

   б) если дата создания попадает в диапазон, то вывести id.

Это алгоритм решения вашей задачи. Каждое из этих действий гуглится, если сами не справитесь: ["С# ввод даты с консоли"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655718/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за пошаговую инструкцию! Очень помогли!